# Is there a way I could report back my robot tests results from Jenkins to slack?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have tests that run on Jenkins. - Robot Framework Tests. 
They run on a scheduled basis, but no one really takes a look.

I wanted to see if there is a mechanism using which, I could report back the results to a slack channel once the job completes executing tests.

```
def branch = "branchName"

node ('AWS-LoadTest') { 
    stage ('Checkout') {
        cleanWs()
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: branch]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '9999999-99999999', url: 'git@github.com:Abcd/abc.git']]]) 
    }
    stage ('Execute Tests'){ 
        def colorCode = '#FF0000'
        def buildStatus = 'FAILURE'
        String slackChannel='#slackChannelName'
        try {
            bat """  
            robot -d outputs --variable ENV:prod -i production TestAutomation/RobotTests/testsuites/test.robot
            """
            buildStatus = 'SUCCESS'
            colorCode = '#00FF00'
        } catch (e) {
            colorCode = '#FF0000'
            def summary = "${buildStatus}: Production Health Check Test, ${env.BUILD_URL}",
            slackSend(channel: slackChannel, color: 'danger', message: """)
            }

         finally {
            step([
            $class : 'RobotPublisher',
            outputPath : 'outputs/',
            outputFileName : "*.xml",
            disableArchiveOutput : false,
            passThreshold : 100,
            unstableThreshold: 80.0,
            otherFiles : "*.png" ])    
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try running this code? Did it work? Was there an error message?

Comment: @MaratC 

```
Started by timer
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 21: unexpected token: ( @ line 21, column 13.
      slackSend(channel: slackChannel, color: 'danger', message: """)
               ^

1 error
```

Comment: Three double-quotes in a row in your `message: """` is not valid Groovy.